# Override or Change Add to Card Button Text Without Backend Code (With Admin Panel)

Tags: magento2, admin, addtocart, luma-theme

I want to Override or Change the text of Add to cart Button, With my Admin Panel.

Don't Want to change in back end Code.
I find some method that add some xml code in particular page in content section and override the main code.
Like:-

```
referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>

referenceBlock name="footer.col.title.1" remove="true"/> "
```

[image]

> So is it possible to change in Add to Cart Button text with some
>   HTML code in my admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Please first override js file from path

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/themename/packagename/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

You have to changes text which you want to from this file.

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Thanks..
i create a simple module.
so can i just copy and past this .js file in my module, dose its work.
or i have to add more file in my module